# Can anyone please explain me what the ‘def displayRMagicSquare(magic_square)’ is asking for exactly?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I want to achieve the expected output by creating two functions. I have included some guidelines within the functions.

```
def createRMagicSquare(row1,row2,row3,row4):
    '''
    A function that creates a Ramanujan magic square  

    Returns
    ----------

    '''


    return magic_square

def displayRMagicSquare(magic_square):

    '''
    A function that displays a Ramanujan magic square  

    Parameters
    ----------

    '''

c = createRMagicSquare([23, 22, 18 ,87], [89, 27, 9 ,25] , [90, 24 ,89 ,16] , [19, 46 ,23 ,11])

displayRMagicSquare(c)
```

Expected output

```
23 22 18 87
89 27 9 25
90 24 89 16
19 46 23 11
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the exact question asked for this problem.

Comment: Okay, I will post the complete question

Answer (score 1):

You are achieving your expected output in `createRMagicSquare()` and i think there is no need of `displayRMagicSquare()`

To createRMagicSquare() you are passing 4 lists,

```
createRMagicSquare([23, 22, 18 ,87], [89, 27, 9 ,25] , [90, 24 ,89 ,16] , [19, 46 ,23 ,11])
```

and they are being grouped into a single list such as,

```
magic_square = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
```

and the line `print(" ".join(map(str,i)))` is converting each list into a string of space seperated elements such as,

```
23 22 18 87
89 27 9 25
90 24 89 16
19 46 23 11
```

and if you still want to use 2 function to print the expected output then,

```
def createRMagicSquare(row1,row2,row3,row4):
    magic_square = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
    return magic_square


def displayRMagicSquare(magic_square):
    for i in magic_square:
        print(" ".join(map(str,i)))
    return magic_square

c = createRMagicSquare([23, 22, 18 ,87], [89, 27, 9 ,25] , [90, 24 ,89 ,16] , [19, 46 ,23 ,11])

displayRMagicSquare(c)
```

Comment: I have to use another function(as it is asked in the question). Moreover this line is also included in my code:  ```c = createRMagicSquare([23, 22, 18 ,87], [89, 27, 9 ,25] , [90, 24 ,89 ,16] , [19, 46 ,23 ,11])

displayRMagicSquare(c)```.So anyway I have to define displayRMagicSquare(c) in order to get the result. I will be posting entire question for your reference. Kindly help

Comment: i have edited my answer please check if it is correct.

Comment: The code seems to be correct but it's not showing the output as expected ---```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable```

Comment: a return statement was needed .I have added it in the code.